# Numerical/artifical damping in forward Euler?

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, simulation

I'm testing a code to find periodic solutions of nonlinear structural vibrating systems by solving a global time-discretized periodic system of equations. I am using a forward Euler (first order explicit) approximation in velocities and accelerations. I find my solution, yet compared to a explicit time marching code, the solution exhibits an increased damping. I've validated the classic time marching signal with a bunch of different methods and they are consistent. From what I understand, forward Euler shouldn't have a numerical damping associated with it right?

How would I mathematically prove if a time discretization produces numerical damping or not?

Comment: Simplest test: crank the step size down an order of magnitude, and investigate the result. Forward euler has a relatively small region of absolute stability compared to other explicit schemes. It's possible that you're over-estimating your first-derivative component (basically leading to increased damping).

Comment: @Arkamis Thanks for the tip: it seems to apply, but since I am solving the entire system of equations for a single period increasing the number of time steps is barely possible. But decreasing the number of time steps shows the opposite effect, the solution is even more damped. Is there a way to circumvent the artificial damping without switching the discretization scheme?

Comment: There's not much you can do if you're working with forward euler. Forward euler is the simplest possible explicit method, it's just a projection of the most fundamental finite difference approximation of the derivative. Step-size is your only free parameter. If your solution is periodic, however, then you might instead be able to re-scale the proble (say, reduce the period), then undo that scale change after solving.

Comment: @Arkamis I see what you mean. Since I am dealing with a non-smooth signal there is not much I can do. I need the forward Euler to clearly approximate the non-smoothness, but get artificial damping. Higher order approximations have far less damping, but are incapable to resolving the non-smoothness nicely. If you make your comment an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, to let the question get answered...

There's not much you can do if you're working with forward euler. Forward euler is the simplest possible explicit method, it's just a projection of the most fundamental finite difference approximation of the derivative. Step-size is your only free parameter. If your solution is periodic, however, then you might instead be able to re-scale the proble (say, reduce the period), then undo that scale change after solving